# Merging of multiple Geo PDF's

Tags: qgis, python, geospatial-pdf

I have a QGIS (v3.22) project where from which I would like to create a multipage geospatial pdf. This feature is sadly disabled. I only have the option to create a geospatial pdf per page or create single PDF without any geospatial info.

Is it possible to merge these afterwards preferably using a python library or other tool?

I checked out pypdf2 but it loses the geospatial info.

Kind regards,

Comment: What behaviour do you expect when loading such a PDF into a GIS?

Comment: I don't want to load the pdf into a gis. I want the gis info to be in the pdf. So that the pdf is clickable and measurable: https://helpx.adobe.com/be_en/acrobat/using/geospatial-pdfs.html. That works for a single page pdf generated by qgis, but not a multipage one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate geospatial pdfs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172607/concatenate-geospatial-pdfs)

Comment: @J.Monticolo No, the pypdf2 solution doesn't work and the other is proprietary

Comment: My comment was for duplicate question, and it seems that the question of the other post is the same as yours. A GIS SE way to search an answer "again" may be to set a bounty on the other post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 0):

Using pdftk in Linux:

```sh
pdftk pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf pdf3.pdf cat output merged123.pdf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sadly, this does not retain the geospatial aspect of the pdf.